# Build a VS project targeting a specific framework and/or build configuration

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

We have a project with multiple target framework, for instance

```
<TargetFrameworks>net47;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
```

If I build with vs, it rebuilds for all frameworks and it is time consuming.

If I build with command line I may choose a specific framework:

```
dotnet  build MyProject.csproj -f netcoreapp3.1 -c MyConfig --no-incremental
```

The question is: during dev, often I need to verify only a target framework and/or a target configuration, How I may select such a specific config/framework using Visual Studio Rebuild without need to run a command line build?

Note that with dependencies it include tens of project, so commenting out the framework I don't want to build, is not a working solution for us.

Thank you!